# Check if a value of an array exist in an object in a different array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to check if a value in array1 exists in an object in array2.

array1:

```
[2,5,1]
```

array2:

```
[
  { value: 1, name:  'Monday', isSelected: false }, 
  { value: 2, name: 'Tuesday', isSelected: false  }, 
  { value: 3, name: 'Wednesday', isSelected: false  },
  { value: 4, name: 'Thursday', isSelected: false  }, 
  { value: 5, name: 'Friday', isSelected: false  },
]
```

What I want to achieve is to check `array1` against `array2` property named `value`. If the value of an object in `array2` is included in `array1`, the `isSelected` property should be updated to true. I've tried:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  array2: prevState.array2.map(el => {
    if (el.value === array2) {
      return {
        ...el,
        isSelected: !el.isSelected
      }
    }
    return el;
  })
}))
```

Comment: You can map array2 and extract only the values `array2.map(a => a.value)` and then loop through it if it contains array1 values

Comment: Try this.. if(array1.indexOf(el.value) > -1){isSelected: !el.isSelected}.
Where el is each object of array2

Comment: What if `array2` starts out with `isSelected` properties that are `true`, or can that never happen? Would you want those properties to remain true, or would you want to set them to `false` if not in `array1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach here is to check array2 against array1. Below is a working code snippet.

```
let values = [
  { value: 1, name:  'Monday', isSelected: false }, 
  { value: 2, name: 'Tuesday', isSelected: false  }, 
  { value: 3, name: 'Wednesday', isSelected: false  },
  { value: 4, name: 'Thursday', isSelected: false  }, 
  { value: 5, name: 'Friday', isSelected: false  },
]

const selectedValues = [2,5,1];

values = values.map((item) => {

  if(selectedValues.indexOf(item.value) > -1) {
    item.isSelected = true;
  }

  return item;
});

console.log(values);
```

And here is the link from jsbin: https://jsbin.com/nikabegobe/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 5):

Inside the `.map` callback, *always* return, and set the `isSelected` property to whether `array1.includes(obj.value)`, where `obj` is the object you're iterating over:

```js
const array1 = [2, 5, 1];
const array2 = [{
    value: 1,
    name: 'Monday',
    isSelected: false
  }, {
    value: 2,
    name: 'Tuesday',
    isSelected: false
  }, {
    value: 3,
    name: 'Wednesday',
    isSelected: false
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    name: 'Thursday',
    isSelected: false
  }, {
    value: 5,
    name: 'Friday',
    isSelected: false
  },
];

const output = array2.map(obj => ({
  ...obj,
  isSelected: array1.includes(obj.value)
}));
console.log(output);
```

It's not entirely clear, but if `isSelected` properties can start out as `true` *and* you want to preserve them, despite the numbers not existing in the `array1`, change to `isSelected: obj.selected || array1.includes(obj.value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `some()` and `includes()`

```
const arr1 = [2,5,1];
const arr2 = [{ value: 1, name:  'Monday', isSelected: false }, { value: 2, name: 'Tuesday', isSelected: false  }, { value: 3, name: 'Wednesday', isSelected: false  },
      { value: 4, name: 'Thursday', isSelected: false  }, { value: 5, name: 'Friday', isSelected: false  },
    ];

let isSelected = arr2.some(obj => arr1.includes(obj.value));

console.log(isSelected)
```